# Display list in HTML, TypeScript, Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to get the information from ski-equipments.ts to be displayed in app.component.html
I need to import skiEquipmentsData from ski-equipments.ts to app.component.ts
ski-equipments.ts and then write some code so I could use the information in app.component.html

ski-equipment.ts

```
export const skiEquipmentsData = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "header": "Nybörjarpaketet",
      "description": "Detta är ett perfekt paket för dig som inte är så van vid att åka, men ändå vill få ut det mesta möjliga av din tid i backen",
      "extendedDescription": "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Atomic Performer FB</li><li>Bindning: M10 GripWalk</li><li>Pjäxa: Nordica Trend LX 20/21</li></p>",
      "imageUrl": "/assets/images/beginner.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "header": "Medelpaketet",
        "description": "Om du har åkt en del och vill ha en lite mer avancerad utrustning ska du välja detta paket. Här får du den bästa kompromissen mellan lättåkta skidor och bra prestanda.",
        "extendedDescription": "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Atomic Redster WT</li><li>Bindning: M10 GripWalk</li><li>Pjäxa: Atomic Hawx Magna 100 21/22</li></p>",
        "imageUrl": "/assets/images/medium.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "header": "Expertpaketet",
        "description": "När du vill ha det bästa som går att få för att känna att din skidåkning kan nå nya höjder är detta paketet för dig. Med denna topputrustning garanterar vi att du kommer att få en riktigt minnesvärd tid i backarna.",
        "extendedDescription": "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Rossignol BlackOps Stargazer (Open) 21/22</li><li>Bindning: Touring Bindings Marker Alpinist 10 21/22</li><li>Pjäxa: Rossignol Alltrack Elite 90 GW (98 mm) 21/22</li></p>",
        "imageUrl": "/assets/images/expert.png"
    }
  ];
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I also need to make a button after every "card" in app.component.html that shows the current id from ski-equipment when it is clicked

app.component.html

```
<br>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3></h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <button>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 2</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 3</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could explain your problem / question. I don't understand where I could help you in your understanding besides just posting the solution.

Comment: Please look at tutorials around Angular, run through them, try a few things, then come back when you have a specific question about a particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

Seems like you are asking two question:

1. How to display a list in an Angular component (it is not clear whether AngularJS or Angular2)?
2. How can I make a button that displays data after it is clicked in Angular?

I will try to answer both of them, assuming for both that you are using Angular2. I will also add a small explanation about components.

### Angular components

According to [Angular documentation about components](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview),

> Components are the main building block for Angular applications

A component has view (html and css files) and logic (ts file), encapsulated in a folder.

When you create an angular app, you start with a component called app. That includes the "app" folder, which contain app.ts and app.html files. I would not suggest to start coding in this component unless you really need to. Instead, create components with specific responsibilities. In your case, you may want to create a "ski-equipments" component, which responsibility is, for example, to display ski equipment available in your store

You normally create components using the command line. If you run `ng g c ski-equipments` in the root folder of your app it will create a folder "src/app/ski-equipments", which will contain ski-equipments.ts, ski-equipments.html, ski-equipments.css and ski-equipments.spec.ts (this last file is for testing, if you are just starting to use Angular I would suggest to delete it). Also, it will modify your app.module, to let your app know where to look for that component.

Once you create your ski-equipments component, you can show it in your app.component.html by adding `<app-ski-equipments></app-ski-equipments>`. This works because your component view (html file) is not just regular HTML, but a template (more on that below).

## How to display a list in an Angular component?

In Angular you write components views using templates, as per [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components):

> A template looks like regular HTML, except that it also contains Angular template syntax, which alters the HTML based on your application's logic and the state of application and DOM data.

Template syntax can be used to show a list in the component's view. You can use the [structural directive NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) for displaying in your component view (.html file) a list that you have in your component logic (.ts file)

Let s assume you created a ski-equipments component. Inside ski-equipments.ts you have a SkiEquipmentsComponent class. You can initialize your skiEquipmentsData array there. It will look something like this:

```
// imports ...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ski-equipments',
  templateUrl: './ski-equipments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ski-equipments.component.css']
})
export class SkiEquipmentsComponent {
  skiEquipmentsData = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "header": "...",
      "description": "...",
      "extendedDescription": "...",
      "imageUrl": "..."
    }
    // other elements of the array
  ]
}
```

Now that you have the list in your component logic, you can just show it by referencing it in your component view, using template syntax. Your ski-equipments.component.html will look something like this:

```
<!-- ngFor is the shortened form of NgForOf mentioned above -->
<div *ngFor="let skiEquipment of skiEquipments">
  <!-- for template syntax anything inside the brackets {{}} is considered an expression, and will try to solve it by looking in the component logic -->
  <p>{{skiEquipment.id}}</p>
  <p>{{skiEquipment.header}}</p>
  <p>{{skiEquipment.description}}</p>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

## How can I make a button that displays data after it is clicked in Angular?

I do not have much time left to finish my answer, so I will just refer you to the [Event Binding documentation](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

In summary, you just want to add `(click)="aFunctionInYourComponentLogic()"` in the template HTML element of your button.

For that function to show the id of the ski-equipment, there are many ways. Maybe a simple one will be to just make visible a  containing that info you want to display.

Comment: *it is not clear whether AngularJS or Angular2* The OP used the tag [angular] which is specific to [Angular](https://angular.io). [angularjs] is used for the now-defunct framework [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org).

Comment: While the amount of work you put into this answer is certainly appreciated, it is unfortunately unlikely to be found, since the question is quite poor (at this point). You may have better luck answering better asked questions.